# The meaning of "What a bum rap"

Tags: meaning

I got that words from novel. I've been looking for the meaning but still can't get what it means. Is that kind of slang?

"Hi, Mr.Tushman! I see you're running a little behind today! Did your car get rear-ended again? What a bum rap!"

Comment: It is good that you have tried looking. Where have you been looking for the meaning and how have you searched?. Did you look for 'bum rap' as a phrase separate from its two constituent parts? Have you tried googling in the format 'define: bum rap? It is, indeed, some kind of *slang*.

Comment: Some online dictionary. But still can't get it.

Comment: A rap is aggression towards you: some form of hatred and you will know what sort of aggression from the novel.  A 'Bum' is a tramp. You may be able to find on line the song "Alleluiah, I'm a bum!" which typified those thrown out of work by the great Wall Street crash. A bum rap reduces your status to that of a tramp.

Comment: @Hugh That is somewhat different from what I've found https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20bum%20rap just because Bum can mean tramp doesn't mean it does in this instance. Bum also means buttocks...

Comment: @Spagirl, another thing I got wrong is the date of the song; it is 1895 or so. But I think that 'unjust prison sentence' is what the tramps, those out of work in recession, expected.

Comment: The _Random House Historical Dictionary of American Slang_ dates "bum rap" as a noun phrase to 1926 and points to two definitions that appeared for it in that year: "A crime which he didn't commit" and "sentence imposed upon one who claims to be innocent." In those definitions, _rap_ seems to connote either "accusation" or "conviction" and _bum_ seems to connote "false." I think the origin of the term would be interesting to investigate, and I am voting to reopen.

Comment: Can you provide a full paragraph (or at least 3 to 5 sentences) where the term was used? After you edit your question, I will vote to reopen your question.

Comment: I've added a pict. But why it doesn't appear?

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bum%20rap

Comment: @Hugh - Wrong!  Check the dictionary.

Comment: @HotLicks Read the question "Hi, Mr.Tushman! I see you're running a little behind today! Did your car get rear-ended again? What a bum rap!"

Comment: @Hugh - You have a point, but but you didn't address the play on words either.

Comment: @HotLicks  Ah, Wonder! 2012,  I'm only a hundred years wrong, though.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, a [bum rap](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bum%20rap) is a false accusation of criminal behavior.  "Rap" is an accusation (consider "rap sheet" still used on cop shows in the US) and "bum", in this sense, means "bad" or "false".

But in the OP's example the term is used as a play on words -- if your car is rear-ended you have been "rapped" on the "bum" (where "bum" in this sense means "buttocks").

(And, of course, "Tushman" is a play on words too, as "tush" is, I think Yiddish, for "buttocks".)

Comment: Not to mention "a little behind"...